# Changing the Date in Raw & JPEG files using the Command Line

Tags: date, jpeg, photo

I have a number of photos which I took in a different time zone — about 10 hours off. As a result half of them have have a date on the wrong day, and all of them have the wrong time.

Is there a command line program I can use to change the embedded date? I know that for JPEG it would be something in the EXIF data, but I don’t know how to change that that. The Raw files are Sony ARW files, so I don’t even know whether that’s possible.

My photos are stored on a Linux server, so I can use the command line there. Failing that, I work on a Mac, so I can use the command line there as well.

The reason I want to use the command line is that there really are a lot of files, so I imagine it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following tool will do the job:

[ExifTool by Phil Harvey     (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

The web site looks very dated, but it is definitely current. Despite the name, which implies JPEG, it will also handle RAW and other formats.